# htaccess trailing slash redirect with Kirby

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, trailing-slash, kirby

Is it possible to redirect a url without trailing slash to the URLs with trailing slash in [Kirby CMS](http://getkirby.com/)? How?

**From**

http://www.test.com/page

**To**

http://www.test.com/page/

**htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
DirectorySlash On
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/kirby/
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)\.(txt|md|mdown)$ error [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^site/(.*) error [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^kirby/(.*) error [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^robots.txt robots.txt [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^panel/(.*) panel/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it, works on localhost as well.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

http://www.paulund.co.uk/using-htaccess-to-force-trailing-slash

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Did not work. I don't know if it has to do with that I'm working on localhost? http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/kirby/projects work but does not get redirected.